# Hide a CPT from specific pages

Tags: custom-post-types

Goodevening,

i create a CPT (newsletter) and i want to hide from specific pages. I try to do that with many ways, but the newsletter not hide.

Edit: 
I want to hide in page subscribe {slug} and 6677 {id}

1) JQuery

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      if (window.location.pathname == "localhost/mysite/subscribe/") {
             $('.subscribe').hide();
      } 
 });
```

2) Conditional tags

```
<?php if(is_page(6677) ) { ?>
<style>
  .subscribe-content{
      display: none!important;
  }
</style>
<?php } ?>
```

3) parameters in CPT array

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'subscribe',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'post__not_in' => array(6677,613),
    'caller_get_posts'=> 1
    );  

  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<?php the_content();?>

     <?php endwhile; else : ?>
        <center><h2> Do nothing</h2></center>
        <?php endif; ?>
      <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your page name is `subscribe`
for Jquery code you have to specifiy pathname not whole wp url ;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
if (window.location.pathname == "/theme/subscribe/") {
 document.getElementsByClassName("subscribe").style.display="none";
      } 
 });
```

in php code  here is same example using page name or slug ;

```
<?php if(!is_page('subscribe') ) { ?>
 <style>.subscribe-content{display: none!important;}</style> 
    <?php } ?>
```

You can use arry to add more than one page 
`if(!is_page(array(6677,613) )`

Comment: yes my page is subcribe (i make the edits in my first post). In your first solution i try to understand the pathename, for the second solution, don't work. Also i add  `<?php if(!is_page('subscribe') ) { ?>` to hide in the pages and works, but for specific page not work.

Comment: OK how you included your CPT to other pages ! for Jquery code full path should look like this `http://yoursite.com/subscribe/` so JS page path should be `/subscribe/`.. and yes if you want hide it from subscribe a not `!` Code should work .

Comment: The CPT included in the footer of website, but with some css i add as "z-index" in all the website. For Jquery : the path is `http://localhost/theme/subscribe/` the problem still remaining.

Answer (score 0):

Form begin i wanted to hide from some pages, like the 'subscribe-page', 'contact form' the project is an eCommerce (Woocommerce).I try with the solutions above, but the problem remained.
The only solution and less time-consuming :

```
<?php get_template_part('parts/subscribe', 'content');?>
```

And i add for every page/category that i want.

Even if the problem solved, i really want to know why the Conditional tags do not work.

Thanks in advanced.